# With tkinter, is it possible to label over the label of a menu object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, menu, tkinter, menuitem

I have created a a menu (attached to a menu button) to which data is written to. The coding for this menu is shown below:

```
global kli
kli = Menubutton(text = "Selective undo", state = DISABLED)
kli.pack(side = "left")
kli.menu = Menu(kli, tearoff = 0)
kli["menu"] = kli.menu
global undo1
undo1 = kli.menu
kli.pack()
```

The menu is written to in another function, in which it is written to, like so:

```
# 'po' is a Point class object and `selectundo` is another function to relevant to this question
undo1.add_command(label = po, command = lambda: selectundo(undo1.index(po)))
```

The menu and menu button *function* perfectly. But,**my issue is that, since I have to index through the menu (for other reasons not relevant), the label for the menu *MUST* be a point object, since the point object contains a function I want to run.** However, because of that, it appears like this:

[image: Tkinter Menu]

I want each item's label to be different from what is actually embedded in the menu function. The only way I can see of solving this is ***putting another label OVER the label of each item as they are added to the menu.*** **Is it possible to to that?** If it is not, is there any other way to display a different label on the item added to the menu than what is embedded inside the `Menu` function? Any help with this issue is much appreciated! :)

**P.S.: I *am* using turtle to for my program, and this menu *must* be a GUI, so, correct me if I am wrong, but I do not think I will be able to use the `curses` module to create this menu.**

**EDIT:** I want to make the function that po contains, which I can receive through po.getfunction(), the label of each item in the menu, while the point object itself stays in the "background" somehow so the program can still index through the menu based on the po objects as a whole, not on the label of each item. I hope this clears up any confusion.

Comment: label is always a text. When you do `label=po` then python convert `po` into text and use this text as label.

Comment: @furas Hey, it's you again! So, how would I convert `po` to text? Do `str(po)` or something like that? I tried using a `Label` widget with making the menu the master, but it did not seem to work.

Comment: you can use any text - event "Hello World" if you need. if `po` has `po.x` and `po.y` then you can use `"x: " + po.x + "  y: " + po.y`

Comment: @furas Well, I have to receive the function from the point class, and I can do this through `po.getfunction()`. Will your method return the function as the label, but still leave `po` (the point object)  in the background?

Comment: In your Point class you will need to define a method called "__ str __" (remove spaces) that will return a string that you want to represent your object. I'm just guessing, but maybe for a Point object you would want `return "({x}, {y})".format(x=self.x, y=self.y)`.

Comment: @SimonAndrews So, define it like `def __str__(): return                                "({function})".format(self.function)`?

Comment: my function only create text for `label`. `label` is for text (displayed in menu), not for `po`. If you need `po` then keep it on some list.

Comment: @R.Kap If self.function would result in a string that represents an instance of your object then sure. Here's a [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/HMbTAznz) that explains what I mean better. The `__str__` method defines what should be returned when you do `str(thing)`.

Comment: @furas I want to make the function that `po` contains, which I can receive through `po.getfunction()`, the label of each item in the menu, while the point object itself stays in the "background" somehow so the program can still index through the menu based on the `po` objects as a whole, not on the label of each item. I hope you get what I mean.

Comment: @SimonAndrews Please look at my most recent comment to furas. Correct me if I am wrong, but your method does not seem to do that.

Comment: well, probably you need this `__str__` function inside Point class but rather `def __str__(self): return self.getfunction()`

Comment: I don't think you will need the getfunction() method at all. I think you had it right with `def __str__(): return "({function})".format(function=self.function)` and I just didn't understand what you wanted back then. http://pastebin.com/APtEUQ6J

Comment: @SimonAndrews Yeah. I really did not need it at all. I actually solved my issue using your method! Thanks!

Comment: @furas Your method works too, but I prefer Simon's method as it looks cleaner.

Comment: @SimonAndrews Please, if you have the time, look at my newest edit.

Comment: @furas Please, if you have the time, look at my newest edit.

Comment: if you have new issues then create new question on SO

Comment: @furas Please go to ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701713/issue-with-differentiating-between-two-of-the-same-items-in-a-tkinter-menu ) for the new issue, if you have the time.